# Userform Initialise with listbox filled with array from cells

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a userform within a userform (userform-ception) where I implement a search function for part list in Row B. Prior to searching I want to check for duplicates, which triggers a second userform when true. I am having trouble populating userform2's list box when it initialises. My logic is

1. If duplicate count > 1, filter by column B for that search criteria
2. Open second userform
3. From the current visible cells, grab the first 7 columns and populate a list box with this (Using visible cells as array)

However when I try to open the userform it turns out blank so I am wondering if anyone can shed some light on this.

This is in my Search Function

```
Dim Dupl As Integer

Dupl = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), PartNumberSearch.Text)

If Dupl > 1 Then

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=PartNumberSearch
    
End With

UserForm2.Show

'Exiting the sub here so that when userform 2 is used to disambiguate the part it can continue to search using PartID instead
Exit Sub
```

This is in my userform2_initialise() function

```
Private Sub UserForm2_Initialize()

DupList.ColumnWidths = "35;50;60;25;10;20;40"

'Checks last row of the list
DupRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Puts all the result into the ResultsList
DupList.List = Range("A2:G" & DupRow).Value
    
End Sub
```

A sample snippet of my table
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `.Value` unless the source range is contiguous.

Comment: If I remove the .value, should this work? I tried it and it didn't.

Comment: You can use the `arrayFromVisibleRows` function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71298681/478884

Comment: Than you for that! This one looks quite complicated for me, I will have to take time to understand the code, but is there an explanation as to why my code doesn't work? I do have similar code that works fine.

Comment: When you call `.Value` on a contiguous range (a rectangular range with no "gaps") you get a 2D array which van be assigned to the listbox's `List` property.  You can't do that with a non-contiguous range: that type of range can't give you a 2D arrays from `.Value`.  So you either have to walk the visible rows in the filtered table and fill cell-by-cell, or use a function like the one I linked to so you can get a 2D array from the filtered data.